# What is the relationship between the Heisenberg uncertainty principle and the principle of complementarity?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

My textbook appears to imply that the [principle of complementarity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity_(physics)) is a consequence of the uncertainty principle:

> The uncertainty principle allows us to understand why it is possible for radiation,
> and matter, to have a dual (wave-particle) nature...we find that an experiment which forces radiation to reveal its wave character strongly suppresses its
> particle character. If we modify the experiment to bring out the particle character, its
> wave character is suppressed. ...This, of course, is the essence of Bohr's principle of complementarity

Why is this the case? Is it that waves have large $\Delta x$ and small $\Delta p$ and particles have small $\Delta x$ and large $\Delta p$? I understand that particles are better at transferring momentum upon interaction but what does this have to do in the uncertainty in the momentum they carry before / after interaction?

Comment: I suspect you have the right idea. Both principles  dramatize the throroughgoingly non-classical nature of QM. Perhaps this is a non-technical philosophical question...

Comment: I think this was proposed  before quantum mechanical theory  was  finalized. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Complementarity_(physics) .